# Grails - Making Methods Globally Available and Metaclass Programming

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming, metaclass

I inserted this line into my init() of my BootStrap class

```
Integer.metaClass.minutes = { 60000L * delegate }
```

I was then not able to use it from a Job class (Quartz plugin). Do I put this line of code somewhere else to make it a global modification?

I was also wondering the best way to make a function available inside all classes in Grails.
Like a global function. Would it be to extend the Object metaclass? or is there a better way?

Comment: You could use the already existing: `def time = use( TimeCategory ) { 10.minutes.toMilliseconds() }`... Although this doesn't answer your question ;-)

Comment: very cool. Can you explain the use and TimeCategory thing? Best reference on it? Awesome +1 on the comment

Comment: @tyndall [`TimeCategory`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/TimeCategory.html) is a Groovy [`Category`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Categories). The `use` function can be thought of as a way to temporarially add functionality to a class, so inside the `use(){ ... }` block, the Category is in effect and integers are decorated with time based properties. Similar to adding a method to the `metaClass`, but more localised.

Comment: NB:  In groovy 1.8, `TimeCategory` has moved to the `groovy.time.*` package, which shouldn't affect things until Grails starts using it (v1.4?)

Comment: @tim_yates actually, TimeCategory exists in the the new location in groovy 1.7.  It should be imported from there even with grails 1.3.

Comment: Categories - wow, just like C# extension methods. Curious, so which came first Categories in Objective C or Extension Methods in C#? Very simple way to extend standard classes - Groovy never ceases to impress me.

Comment: Would `ExpandoMetaClass.EnableGlobally()` before that line work as well, or does that do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I put this line of code somewhere else to make it a global modification?

Use the [DelegatingMetaClass](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Using+the+Delegating+Meta+Class.html)

> I was also wondering the best way to make a function available inside all classes in Grails. Like a global function. Would it be to extend the Object metaclass? or is there a better way?

If you want the function to be an instance method of all classes, then you must add it to the metaClass of `Object` (see above). If not, simply add the function as a static method of a class, i.e. the same way you make functions globally accessible in Java.

Comment: On the second part of the question, I was looking to create a quickdial function for something I have to do all the time. Ex. use GORM to quickly grab me the User in my system based off a FacebookID. FYI - "Quickdial" as in the jQuery $ or the UnderscoreJS _ I didn't want to use an odd character just a really short method name.

Comment: Ok. Thought I had this working. No such luck. Where do you put the class in the StringMetaClass example? I'm using the second method in the article. In src/groovy?