# Correct way to metaprogram in grails so its available in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails, metaprogramming

I can add a method to the java Integer type in Groovy with the lines:

```
ExpandoMetaClass.EnableGlobally()
Integer.metaClass.gimmeAP = {->return 'p'}
```

I don't know why I'd need that, but it gets the point across.  Now I can make calls to Integers and get back a 'p'.  Now lets say I want this in a grails app so I can make calls in the domain objects.  The specific problem I'm having is that when I put those metaprogramming lines in the bootstrap all the metaprogramming isn't available in the unit tests, so my unit tests are failing with errors like "No method gimmeAP for java.lang.Integer" or something like that.

How do I either include the metaprogramming better, or execute that part of the bootstrap so I can use my tricked out syntax in unit tests?

I have seen this question: [Grails - Making Methods Globally Available and Metaclass Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454000/grails-making-methods-globally-available-and-metaclass-programming) and it seems my line `ExpandoMetaClass.EnableGlobally()` may fix his problem, but am I using it right?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap isn't executed for unit tests. I would personally prefer to create a mockFoo method that does the above meta programming, and Then I will call the mockFoo from the test setup. 
Also look at the GrailsUnitTestCase.registerMetaClass. Register metaclass before you add mock methods, so that they don't leak in other tests.

```
    registerMetaClass(SecurityUtils)
    SecurityUtils.metaClass.'static'.getSubject = { ->
        return [logout: { return true } ] as Subject
    }
```

I know you want to make your dynamic methods available to all unit tests, but there's nothing such as bootstrap for unit tests. So you have to do it in each test.

You can create a MockHelper with a static method, and call it from test setUp.