# How to include groovy in a grails project

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming

I'm an idiot or something, and I don't know how to add groovy into src/groovy and make it work.  Lets say I got some meta stuff in my bootstrap and I want to move those calls to a class I can call from unit tests or wherever based on this question:  [Correct way to metaprogram in grails so its available in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884756/correct-way-to-metaprogram-in-grails-so-its-available-in-unit-tests)

So if I put this in my bootstrap (which has `import myproject.*` at the top) it works.

```
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
Integer.metaClass.gimmeAP = {->return 'p'}
assert 3.gimmeAP() == 'p'
```

So I'm using STS and I go into src/groovy and say "New GroovyClass" add it to package myproject and fill it in as so:

```
package yakit

class MetaThangs {
  def doMetaThangs() {
    ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()

    Integer.metaClass.gimmeAP = {->return 'p'}
  }
}
```

Then I call this in bootstrap:

```
MetaThangs.doMetaThangs()
assert 3.gimmeAP() == 'p'
```

I get the error:

```
Running Grails application..
2012-02-07 14:12:13,332 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static lrnmeta.MetaThangs.doMetaThangs() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: doMetaThangs()
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static lrnmeta.MetaThangs.doMetaThangs() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: doMetaThangs()
at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:251)
at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:244)
at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:220)
at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:33)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static lrnmeta.MetaThangs.doMetaThangs() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: doMetaThangs()
at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:5)
... 26 more
Application context shutting down...
Application context shutdown.
```

Is it really telling me I should be typing 'doMetaThangs()' instead of 'doMetaThangs()'?

UPDATE:  based on @mkoryak answer I have tried changing the method declaration in MetaThangs.groovy to:

```
static def doMetaThangs(){
  ...
}
```

It didn't work at first, but eventually it came around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doMetaThangs is not static, but you are calling it as if it was.

either add the static modifier to the method, or call it on an instance of the class, not the class.

Comment: how do I "add the static modifier to the method"?

Comment: I don't know how to do either of those solutions.

Comment: @Mikey You make a function static by putting the word `static` in front of it, just like the exception message shows. To call a method on an instance, create an instance, and call the method on it, like, say `"foo".toUpperCase()`. You might want to take a step back and figure out some basic Java/Groovy stuff before going too much further.